# What is my errors cause in R?

Tags: cluster-computing

I want to use "ARIMA" model in R. >

```
mod1 <- arima  (output, order=c(1,1,0), xreg=default.input)
Error in solve.default(res$hessian * n.used, A) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.42491e-33
```

what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This usually means your matrix is not invertible so that it cant be used for the regression model.